# find trigonometric form of complex number z=1+i*tg(a)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

[there is first condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyzK8.png)

[and there is second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUoVC.png)

Pls help me I'm getting mad more and more
I don't know where to start from, just give me a single tip. I know the formula $z=x+iy$. From there I know $x=1, \:y=\tan(a)$, am  I right? so then why I was given interval of $-\pi<a<\pi$ and $a\ne  \pi/2$.

What  can I do with this?
I don't want a solution, just give me tip, so then I can move forward, ty.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: You're right – except the angle is $\alpha$.

Comment: sorry, i'm new to this site. i'm getting used to it, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:
Compute the modulus first:
$$r^2=1+\tan^2a=\frac1{\cos^2a},\quad\text{whence}\quad r=\frac1{|\cos a|}.$$
Next, factor out the modulus.

Comment: if i understand it right, then i need this interval to refactor out the modulus?

Comment: I just answered the question in the title, I didn't check with the links.

Comment: ok man, thank you a lot, you saved me